# I'm not able to add new product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with WooCommerce not able to add a new product from the admin,

```
 Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_gallery_image_ids() on bool in 
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-images.php:37
```

I have tried disabling all plugins and changed the theme in Twenty Twenty-One, but I still have the same problem. not sure if this is related to a third-party plugin or something with the database.

Comment: Is there an update for the plugin?

Comment: not sure, I have updated all plugins, WordPress, and Woocommerce to the newest version, but still doesn't work. I know that some of the products are changed to revision. As well I see that id's in wp_post are not incrementing properly. Some of them have (9223372036854771520), thick is almost close to bigint maximum, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a database issue.
`get_gallery_image_ids()` calls, as the function name suggests, image ids from the woocommerce database tables. There is probably an option to upgrade your database in a system message somewhere. If not, your database will likely no longer work with woocommerce and you need to restore to an older backup. if you don't have any backups, you should export all of your post data using either the built in import/export tool or using woocommerces' import/export tool and set up a new installation.

That's about all I can think of. Hope this finds you well, and best of luck in your recovery.

Cheers, Kris